# how can I make my python discord bot detect a certain user being mentionned in a command?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to get a command to have an exception where, when the bot itself is pinged, a different message is sent, instead of the generic normal one. And I cant seem to find a certain command that works to my favor in discord.py, any suggestions?

````
@bot.command()
async def fight(ctx):
    if (insert the scanned mention == 'insert discord bot ping'):
        await ctx.send('message')
        await ctx.send('another message')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all the mentioned users by using `ctx.message.mentions`. In case you have the `Member`/`User` instance of that person, you can just do `member.mentioned_in(message)`, or in your case:

```
if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
    # do something here
```

In case you don't have the `Member` instance, you can iterate over `ctx.message.mentions`, and check each one to see if they're the one you needed to check for.

```
id = 12345678910  # The Discord id of the member you want to check
for user in ctx.message.mentions:
    if user.id == id:
        # do something here
```